# In C, when would type casting a char to an integer not return a value between 0 and 127?

Tags: c, char

A common interview question asks to write an algorithm that detects duplicates in a string.
Using a character array of length 128 to keep track of the characters already seen is a good way to solve this problem in linear time.

In C we would type something like

```
char seen_chars[128];
unsigned char c;

/* set seen_chars to all zeros, assign c */

seen_chars[ c ] = 1;
```

To mark character c as seen. Of course this relies on

```
(int) c
```

returning a value between 0 and 127.

I'm wondering when would this fail? What are the assumptions that make this code work correctly?

Comment: Question is a little confusing - in the title you say "casting a char to an integer" but in the question itself you are casting an `unsigned char` to `int`. You might want to make the title consistent with the question, or *vice versa*.

Comment: Writing `(int)c` is meaningless; it has exactly the same value as `c` by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will fail (and cause undefined behavior) every time when the integer value of the given `char c` is not between 0 and 127 (inclusive).

C does in no way limit the maximum range of `char` - you are only guaranteed that it can hold at least 256 distinct values - so in any given C implementation a valid char value can be out of that boundary. On most desktop systems a `char` can hold values from -128 to 127, or from 0 to 255. However, as an example:

```
char aFunction(void);
char c = aFunction();
if ((int)c > 1000000000)
    printf("This could be true on some systems\n").
```

The following would be valid (although it may exhaust your stack on systems with large `char`s):

```
#include <limits.h>
_Bool seen[1<<CHAR_BIT] = {0};
seen[(unsigned char)c] = 1;
/* etc. */
```

Comment: This won't be true on any sane compiler/computer combination (edit: or at least I don't think so) , but it's still an important point: Integral types' sizes (as well as many other types' sizes) are not guaranteed to be X!

Comment: @delnan: True for desktop systems. However, some embedded systems have 32-bit or even 64-bit(!) `char` type.

Answer (score 3):

On most implementations, an `unsigned char` has a value going from 0 to 255. Now, ASCII defines values from 0 to 127, but if your string contains characters from an "extended ASCII" character set (Latin1, for instance), then you might get character values above 127.

So, if your text is american, you're safe. Otherwise, you will overflow your buffer.

Comment: Or if you don't use `char` for characters (as in, text) at all - e.g. for binary data.

Comment: Would this be a property of the compiler or the input text? Or both?

Comment: @Frank The input text is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It works with all 7-bit ascii characters. Other characters, like german umlauts, would be translated to a negative number, with the appropriate consequences for your algorithm.

You're on the safe side if you use unsigned char and make the array 256 entries wide.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering when would this fail?

1. Whenever you have any characters above 127.
2. Whenever you have a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8.